# How to delete a specific row MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get my PHP script to delete a specific row from a table. Every row has an unique ID. However, my code deletes always the first row, while for instance I want it to delete the row where I clicked the button.

```
$task_id = $row_list['task_id'];
if (!empty($_GET['delete'])) {
mysql_query("DELETE FROM to_do.list WHERE list.task_id=$task_id");
header('Location: http://localhost/to_do/list_view.php');
};
```

Table + trigger for script:

```
do { ?>
<?php echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row_list['task_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row_list['task_info'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<form action=script.php method=get name=delete>
                    <input type=hidden name=delete value=$task_id>
                    <input type=submit value=Delete></form>" . "</td>"; ?>
<?php } while ($row_list = mysql_fetch_assoc($list));
echo "</table>" ?>
```

I am not sure how I can make it work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not setting `$task_id` other than via the post, so when you print your form it's undefined. Try using: `value={$row_list['task_id']}>`

Comment: You are referencing a different table in the `WHERE` condition than the table you are deleting from so I guess you are lucky only one row gets deleted...

Comment: @scragar This seemed to do the tric, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Maybe

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
mysql_query("DELETE FROM to_do.list WHERE list.task_id = $_GET['delete']");
header('Location: http://localhost/to_do/list_view.php');
};
```

and

```
echo "<td>" . "<form action=script.php method=get>
                    <input type=hidden name=delete value=$task_id>
                    <input type=submit name=submit value=Delete></form>" . "</td>"; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks as well. With the combination of scragar's comment, it also worked ;)

Comment: Really? A $_GET variable directly in the SQL query?